# How to select a tab on Angular UI programmatically?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/r8W3D6lpb03FH7tkok6T?p=preview) I have three tabs that are created from an array. When I click on the button, I need the one named "Name 1" to be selected and have the focus. How can this be achieved?

HTML

```
<uib-tabset>
   <uib-tab ng-repeat="t in tabs" heading="{{t.title}}" >
     {{t.content}}
   </uib-tab>
</uib-tabset>


<br/><br/><br/>
<button ng-click="tabs.select(1)">Focus on Name 1</button>
```

Javascript

```
  $scope.tabs = [
    { title:'Name 0', content: "Content 0" },
    { title:'Name 1', content: "Content 1" },
    { title:'Name 2', content: "Content 2" }
  ];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to setting the `active` *attribute*, as below:

```
<uib-tabset active="active">
```

Then in your button:

```
<button ng-click="active = 1">Focus on Name 1</button>
```

Here's the forked [**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/k2QQ4w8ZZDL0PPl9bFl7?p=preview).